# Javascript then without promise return val

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

Perhaps i'm not googleing correctly. does a then function without a paramater not block? for instance, you have a promise:

```
someFunc = () => {
  return new Promise((res,rej)=>{
   somethingAsync(input).then((val) => res(val))
  })
}
```

in the following implements of our function. would both wait for the someFunc return val?

```
someFunc().then(dosomethingafter())
someFunc().then((val) => dosomethingafter())
```

Comment: your `someFunc` uses the [Promise constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it). It should just be `someFunc = () => somethingAsync(input)`

Comment: `foo(bar())` will always execute `bar` first and pass the return value to `foo`. It doesn't matter what these functions are doing. Arguments are always evaluated before the function is called.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In JS expressions are eagerly evaluated. It means every function argument is evaluated **before** it's passed.

```
someFunc().then(dosomethingafter())
```

is effectively identical to

```
var tmp = dosomethingafter();
someFunc().then(tmp)
```

so a function `someFunc().then(dosomethingafter())` is invoked before `then` is called, and its returned result is passed as a parameter.

What you probably meant instead is

```
someFunc().then(dosomethingafter)
```

note there is no function call - only a reference to a function is passed to `then` and it would then be called when a promise is resolved.

Answer (score 3):

It is easier to illustrate this via examples. Your first case:

```js
const fn = (text) => {console.log(text)}

const waiter = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  return setTimeout(() => {
    fn('resolved')
    resolve()
  }, 2000)
})

waiter().then(fn('done'))
```

Notice that `fn` got executed first, got evaluated and then the `waiter` got executed.

Lets look at the 2nd case:

```js
const fn = (text) => {console.log(text)}

const waiter = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  return setTimeout(() => {
    fn('resolved')
    resolve()
  }, 2000)
})

waiter().then(() => fn('done'))
```

Notice now that we got `resolved` first and then `done`.

So the answer to your question is yes in both cases we will **wait and execute** the `someFunc` or in the above example the `waiter`.

The main difference really is when does your `dosomethingafter` get executed.

In the first case it is right away and then it is passed in the `waiter`.

In the second case you have a valid promise chain which will first be executed and then once done (and since `fn` acts as the function handler of the `then`) it will execute  `dosomethingafter`.

Answer (score 1):

pass doSomethingafter first class

```
const handleAsJson = response => response.json()
fetch(url)
  .then(handleAsJson)
  .then(console.log)
```