# React not updating data on parent component after child component form submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks

I have a parent component that should be updated when the form on the child component is submitted.  When the form is submitted in the child component, the fetchData function is being called, however, the data is not updated in the parent component here, and requires a page refresh to update the data:

```
{JSON.stringify(data)}
```

I cannot add the **data** from the setState to useEffect because it would create an infinite loop.

How do I update the data on the parent component when submitting the form from the child component?

#### parent component

```
export function ParentComponent() {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);

    const fetchData = async () => {

        const result = await axios(
          '/api/info/'
          );
          setData(result.data)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
      },[]);


      return (
        <div>
            <h1>
                Parent Page
            </h1>
            
            {JSON.stringify(data)}

            <ChildComponent dataUpdated={fetchData} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

#### child component

```
export function ChildComponent(props) {
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState('');

    const handleSubmit = evt => {
            evt.preventDefault();
            axios.post(`/api/info/create`,
                        {formData}
                  )
                  .then(response => { return response.data })
                  .then(props.dataUpdated()) // calling this function does not update the data on the parent component
        }
        
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>
                Child Component
            </h1>

            <form className={classes.form} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <TextField value={formData.number}
                        id="filled-number"
                        label="number"
                        type="number"
                        onChange={evt => setFormData({...formData, number: evt.target.value})}
                    />

                    <Button
                        type="submit"
                    >
                        Submit
                    </Button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: The last `then` in the child should be `props.dataUpdated` without `()` afterwards

Comment: @fast-reflexes, that worked thanks, but why does it work?  How is the function expression being called without the parenthesis?

Comment: I believe I found the reason.  As functions are eagerly evaluated, the function how I had it written would have been called before the then is called. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52769736/3856624

Comment: Answer is that `.then` takes a function as argument, when you do `props.dataUpdated()` you RUN the function and give its return value for the `then` to run whenever it should. The return value of `fetchData` is `undefined`, so you're passing `undefined` as argument to the `then`, which of course does not work. When you remove the parenthesis, you supply the `then` with a function with 0 parameters that works well to run when it should.

Comment: @fast-reflexes, if you make this an answer, I'll accept it.  Thank you for the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the parenthesis from this line:

```
.then(props.dataUpdated())
```

so that it is instead:

```
.then(props.dataUpdated)
```

### Why?

Well this is a common mistake with `Promise`s (which I supposed is returned from `axios.post()`), namely that we tend to forget that the argument to the `then`, `catch` and `finally` functions of the `Promise` should be functions which are executed asynchronously as the `Promise` returns.

Otherwise, a `Promise` is like a regular class / object and in this case you're synchronously running its `then` function two times with different arguments. But like always, when we supply an argument to a function that is, itself, a function call, this call executes first and its return value is given as the actual argument.

So when you do:

```
.then(props.dataUpdated())
```

... you're synchronously (that is, before the `Promise` has returned) running the `props.dataUpdated` function and handing its returns value as the argument to `then`. Since `props.dataUpdated` = `fetchData` returns `undefined` (doesn't have a return value), this is the same as:

```
.then(undefined)
```

... which will not work.

Remember, the argument function is supposed to be executed asynchronously at a later stage (when the `Promise` resolves) but now instead you run it instantly and then leave the `then` function with an `undefined` to execute when the `Promise`  resolves. Since the changed state has not yet occurred, running the update function at this premature time doesn't result in anything and since running `undefined` as a function later doesn't result in anything either, you're left with a UI that is not updated as expected (you might have an error in the console as well from when the `then` tries to run the `undefined` as a function).

### To sum it up...

... you need to supply the `then` with an executable function containing the logic you want to run when the `Promise` returns asynchronously (like you have done in the first `then` already). The easiest way to do this here would be:

```
.then(props.dataUpdated) // forwarding the function given in props
```

... but you could also do:

```
.then(res => props.dataUpdated()) // arrow function calling the function given in props
```

or

```
.then(res => { props.dataUpdated() }) // arrow function with body calling the function given in props
```

... which would be handier if you wanted to do something with the input from the previous step, namely the value that you return from the previous `then` (`response.data`).

### References

- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
- [`Promise`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)